# Deleting app data crashes Xamarin android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing a simple android application with Xamarin. The App contains 3 buttons, and when a button is clicked it adds a new fragment to the activity.

The apk takes more than 40mb of storage space flash drive, what makes a simple app like this so big?

After I deleted the app's data (from android setting menu), it crashes and doesn't run on subsequently when I attempt to launch it.

Is there some data that is essential to launch the app that is stored here, if so why?.[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huL1K.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like you cleared data on a "Debug" install, do **not** do that, you will need to re-install as that "data" is needed for debugging.  Release builds would not have that issue. Archiving and creating a release `.apk` will produce smaller packages... : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: Ou! I'm forget about debug ) Thks yu.